# How to check if Xvfb is (already) running on display :0?

Tags: xorg

Title says it all. `pgrep Xvfb` only does half of the trick. It will not tell me the display number.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you can check whether a X Display is available by running "x display info":

```
xdpyinfo -display :0 >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "In use" || echo "Free"
```

Note: if you cannot access the display, it'll be reported as "Free" too. Another way is checking for the existence of `/tmp/.X0-lock` which contains the PID file of a X server.

Instead of displaying the command, a more reliable way would be checking for processes matching the binary:

```
pids=$(pidof /usr/bin/Xvfb)
if [ -n "$pids" ]; then
    processes="$(ps --format command --no-headers -ww --pid $pids)"
else
    echo "Not running"
fi
```

Source: https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/blob/master/install-files/common-functions#L112

Comment: `xdpyinfo` does the trick for me, thanks! Btw. I want to set the DISPLAY env variable based on Xvfb running on :0.

Comment: See https://github.com/pjg/dotfiles/commit/83a27c8400c78809f5

Comment: So you're trying to get the display number used by Xvfb? Try using the ps command in my answer and use something like `display=":${processes##*:}";display="${%% *}"` to get the display number (assuming it's given with the command which is done for `Xorg` at least)

Comment: I will have it running only on `:0`, so simple check for `:0` is sufficient for my needs. Thanks again!

Comment: I disagree with process checking.  The process can be running but hasn't initialized fully.  xdpyinfo seems like it would be a better solution since I assume it is communicating with Xvfb.

Comment: @Lekensteyn I gave you a +1 a while back because this was helpful to me. I successfully use `xdpyinfo -display :0 >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "(Xvfb is already running.)" || echo "IMPORTANT! Need to run: Xvfb -ac :0 -screen 0 1280x1024x16 &"`. I'm wondering if you could help me convert it into an if-else statement so that it can automatically start Xvfb when necessary. What would be a boolean that I could test? I'm new to bash scripts. Thanks!

Comment: @Ryan That is an easy one, `condition && command-if-true || command-if-false` translates to `if condition; then command-if-true; else command-if-false; fi`. See for example http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html

Comment: @Lekensteyn Thanks for the link. Unfortunately `if [xdpyinfo -display :0 >/dev/null 2>&1]; then echo "Xvfb was already running."; else echo "I will start Xvfb here once I learn if-else."; fi` *always* runs the "else" statement (always outputs `-bash: 1]: ambiguous redirect [new line] I will start Xvfb here once I learn if-else.`). So I'm misunderstanding the `xdpyinfo -display :0 >/dev/null 2>&1` part. It correctly acted as a boolean in our approach with `&&` and `||` in the above comment, but now it's causing this weirdness.

Comment: The syntax for a conditional check is `if ...; then ...; fi`. The `[` is short for `test` (see this manual page: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html).Try removing the `[` and `]`